# Landscape orientation when i show HTML5 video

Tags: iphone, html5-video, mobile-webkit, device-orientation

i have a iPhone application in portrait mode that show a webview. In the webview there is an HTML5 video and i woutl show it in landscape mode.

So i have in my ViewControlleDelegate method (because my application is only in portrait mode):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return NO;
}
```

So there is a way from webkit or in my application to switch in landscape mode only when i showing a HTML5 video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:animated:]`. I think it must help you.